# Access to Laravel app from Android phone in local network

Tags: android, laravel, apache, localhost, host

I have a problem. I build an app with Laravel on my computer (IP: 192.168.1.121), I try to access to my app with my Android phone in local network. When I try to reach 192.168.1.121/myapp/public I have a 404 not found but in my computer all work.

On another computer, I can modify host file to add

```
192.168.1.121     edcintra.test
```

And that works perfectly.

```
define ROOT "C:/laragon/www/EDCIntra/public/"
define SITE "EDCIntra.test"

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "${ROOT}"
    ServerName ${SITE}
    ServerAlias *.${SITE}
    <Directory "${ROOT}">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "${ROOT}"
    ServerName ${SITE}
    ServerAlias *.${SITE}
    <Directory "${ROOT}">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.key
 
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my conf in Apache... Someone already have this problem?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/4779963/2930834

Comment: run ```ipconfig```  and get your local IP then  run ```php artisan serve --host 192.168.x.x (your ip)```

  now you can access your project on ur phone using the same IP

Comment: This link might have answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you all for share this thread i don't see it before !
And really thank you PsyLogic this fixed my problem ! :)